# cordova file transfer error code 1 for languages other than english in ios

Tags: android, ios, cordova, file-transfer

I got `error code 1`(file not found) while downloading a file with the name that consists of the characters other than English from cordova file transfer in ios. 
It works fine with android.

My file name is "`1-Contrôle Réseaux Désenfumage`".

Any help on this will be highly appreciated

Comment: Do you have any more details about the error? Like error messages or the code which does the downloading...

Comment: download error source http://10.0.0.8:20844/Data/555db1f7e853931cd4d1e7d8/JsonDocument/1-Contr%C3%B4le%20R%C3%A9seaux%20D%C3%A9senfumage.txt            upload error code1

Comment: not only with the other language characters but also with the spaces in the file name